# I need return multiple values from an Observable in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to return these values from an observable, but I don't know how to conform the code.

```
getWorkers(filter?: any): Observable<{data: Worker[], info: any}> {
    const url =  API_URL + Config.getWorkers;

    return this.http.get<Worker[]>(url + '?businessId=' + `${filter}`, ).pipe(
               tap(_ => console.log('fetched wirkers')),                
               catchError((error: any) => of(error)));
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be to use the `map` operator:

```
  getWorkers(filter?: any): Observable<{data: Worker[], info: any, error?: any}> {
    const url = API_URL + Config.getWorkers;

    return this.http.get<Worker[]>(url + '?businessId=' + `${filter}`, )
    .pipe(
      tap(
        () => console.log('fetched wirkers')
      ),
      map(
        (workers: Worker[]) => {
          return {
            data: workers,
            info: {}
          };
        }
      ),
      catchError(
        (error: any) => of({ data: [], info: {}, error })
      )
    );
  }
```

More detailed info [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/)

In case of error this approach is returing an empty array `data: []`, empty `info: {}` and the `error` itself.